# mysql - update, insert, or delete a list of row values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My situation is for tracking order ids.  I have a separate table which is linked to a main account through `account_id`.

In my account management I allow the order id's to be added, edited, deleted.  For example, in my form I would show the order ID's as order1,order2,order3,order4.  While this shows them in a comma sep string each has its own row in the `accounts_orders` table.

What logic should be used here as far as editing and updating the database?  All I can think of is a comparison between my new list and the current list in the database.

If in new list, but not in current... add it.  If not in new list, but in current... delete it.

Is there any easier way to go about this?  I do not want to delete all records and insert new ones... as that would increase my primary key much more than necessary.

I am not looking for a code solution, but more of the logic as it seems there must be an easier way to update/insert/delete the new list of values with that which is in the database so they are equal.

```
accounts_orders
---------------  
order_id (primary auto inc)
account_id (foreign key)
order_ref (unique)
```

Comment: `REPLACE INTO` might be what you're looking for, it creates new rows or modifies already existing ones

Comment: No, whatever list of ID's given must match what is in the db. What is in the database could already exist, not exist, or exist and need removed.

Comment: I don't understand why it would have any impact on the PK. !?!

Comment: I am going to assume you mean storing all the order ids in one column... yeah, these needs to be searched and used from the database so this is why they have their own table and rows.

Comment: order_id IS NOT THE PK to this table. The PK is (order_id,account_id)!

Comment: How so?  Explain what you are thinking/talking about.

Comment: order_id is a unique auto'inc'ed key.  Whenever something is inserted it is auto'inc'ed.  Deleting all rows and inserting the new list will create new values.  These will quickly get larger and larger.

Comment: order_id would be a PK in the orders table. It's unlikely that you would want to delete orders

Comment: These are in the orders table... and yes, I do want to be able to remove order_ref's which would be the entire row.

Comment: Don't worry about the ids incrementing. If you're concerned, just set it to BIGINT. Assuming someone places an order every second, it'll be 5000 years before you're even 1 billionth of the way through available numbers. Maybe someone will have come up with a better solution by then.

Comment: That doesn't even relate to this... the problem is if an account has 1000 order rows and there is an edit.  You now deleted 1000 rows and inserted 1000 new ones. Now is has inc'ed 1000 times on that edit.  This will also affect the index as well.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following...

```
CREATE TABLE account_orders
(account_id INT NOT NULL,order_id INT NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(account_id,order_id));

INSERT INTO account_orders VALUES
(1,101),(1,102),(1,103);
```

Now, you can add, edit or delete/dis-associate accounts and orders